# TCPDF, $htmlContent & writeHtml() Alternative

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, tcpdf

I'm learning how to use TCPDF with CakePHP 3.x, & I want to know if there is any alternative to write directly the HTML code instead of writing it inside the Php variable(ex: `$htmlContent`), and after that, passing it through the `writeHtml()` function.

Actionnely I want to do this:

```
$htmlContent='
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <strong> <h3 style="margin-left: 20px"> '. __("Deliveryrun").'</h3> </strong>
                </div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlContent,true,0,true,0);
```

instead of this:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
                    <strong> <h3 style="margin-left: 20px"> '. __("Deliveryrun").'</h3> </strong>
                </div>
```

if it's possible, can you tell me how ?

Thank you

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing so... so, it would probably be good if you'd describe the problem that you're having with it.

Comment: @ndm when I wrote directly the HTML Code, I got an empty pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write directly HTML, but you will need some way how to pass it to the TCPDF. This way will always have to be a variable, argument to the `writeHTML` method.

Your first case is probably the easiest. But if you insist on writing directly HTML, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), that will let you write HTML, then pick it up into some variable that can be passed to the `writeHTML` function, such as:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<div class="col-whatever">
  <h3>Write HTML you need</h3>
<?php
htmlContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->writeHTML(htmlContent,true,0,true,0);
```

but that does not look very nice.